# TypeError: store.getState is not a function in react-redux

Tags: react-redux

I followed the instructions and created the store from this library

```
https://github.com/jesperorb/redux-cart
```

src/store/index.js:

````
import { createStore } from 'redux';
//Import our rootreducer from '../reducers/index.js' this hold our whole state
import rootReducer from  '../reducers/index.js';

/**
  * @param {Object} initialState
 */
export default function store() {
    return createStore(
      rootReducer,
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    );
}
```
````

src/actions/cart-actions.js:

```
/** We don't have to use the variable 'payload', we can also just name it: 'item'
    * @param {Object} item
    */
    export function addToCart(item) {
      return {
          type: 'ADD',
          item: item
      };
    }

    export function removeFromCart(item) {
      return {
          type: 'REMOVE',
          item: item
      };
    }
```

src/index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import store from './store/index.js';


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
  <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

but i get the error `TypeError: store.getState is not a function`. Can someone propose what steps should i look into first?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to create a `store` object in `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import Store from './store/index.js';

// forgot to create store obj
const store = Store();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
  <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: thank you! So you must create a store in the component you have your provider i guess- usually the top one?